# How to compute the kernel of a linear transformation?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

> For each of the following maps T : M2×2(R) → R, determine whether T is a linear transformation
>   or not.
>   and its dimension.
>   (a) The trace map T = tr.
>   (b) The map T that sends A ∈ M2×2(R) to the length of its second column, regarded as
>   a vector in R
>   2
>   .

I know that they are both linear transformations but I do not understand how to find the matrix representation of the linear transformations and the kernel. Could someone help me?

Comment: (b) is not additive. Take two matrices having $(1,0)^t$ and $(0,1)^t$ as their second column. The map $T$ sends them to $1$. But their sum has second column equal to $(1,1)^t$, which gets sent to $\sqrt{2}\neq 2$.

Comment: Oh I see, I misunderstood the question previously. Thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: Would you know how to find the kernel of a?

Comment: Kernel means the elements of the domain that are sent to zero. That means that it consists of the matrices with trace equal to zero. Since they are $2\times 2$ matrices, that means that the two elements in the main diagonal are one the opposite of the other.

Answer (score 0):

You now know that only (a) is a linear transformation, so let us find the matrix of that transformation and its kernel.

The matrix of a transformation depends on the ordered basis for $M_{2 \times 2}(\Bbb R)$, so let us assume that the ordered basis is
$$\left\{
\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&0\end{bmatrix} = \epsilon_1,
\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\0&0\end{bmatrix} = \epsilon_2,
\begin{bmatrix}0&0\\1&0\end{bmatrix} = \epsilon_3,
\begin{bmatrix}0&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix} = \epsilon_4\right\} = \mathscr B.$$

The matrix of $\mbox{tr}$ is a $1 \times 4$ matrix $C$ such that $\mbox{tr }A = C[A]_{\mathscr B}$ where $[A]_{\mathscr B}$ is the coordinate matrix of $A$, which, in this case, is a $4 \times 1$ column matrix whose entries are the coefficients of the elements of $\mathscr B.$

The $i$th entry of $C$ is $\mbox{tr } \epsilon_i.$  Now,
$$\begin{align}
\mbox{tr } \epsilon_1 = 1,\\
\mbox{tr } \epsilon_2 = 0,\\
\mbox{tr } \epsilon_3 = 0,\\
\mbox{tr } \epsilon_4 = 1,\end{align}$$
so the matrix of $\mbox{tr}$ is $\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 & 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}.$

The kernel of $\mbox{tr}$ is the set of all $2 \times 2$ matrices $A$ such that $\mbox{tr } A = 0,$ which, it is clear, is the set of all $A$ of the form
$$\begin{bmatrix}
a_{11} & a_{12}\\
a_{21} & -a_{11}\end{bmatrix}$$
where those entries are any real number.